# Iterative expression of high order derivative

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics

Let $F(x)=xG(x^2)$, I would like to express the derivative of $G$ of any order in terms of the derivative of $F$ and the derivatives of lower degree of $G$.
For example, $$G^{(3)}(x^2)=\dfrac{1}{8x^4}(F^{(3)}(x)-24x^2G^{''}(x^2)-6G'(x^2)).$$
The goal is to find $$G^{(k)}(x^2)=a_k F^{(k)}(x)+a_{k-1}G^{(k-1)}(x^2)+a_{k-2}G^{(k-2)}(x^2)+...$$
It is like a combinatorial problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula

Comment: I hoped it was less complicated as expression

Answer (score 0):

The answer is
$$
\begin{split}
G^{(k)}(x^2)=\dfrac{1}{2^kx^{k+1}}&\left[F^{(k)}-\sum_{m_1+2m_2=k-1}\dfrac{k!}{m_1!m_2!}(2x)^{m_1}G^{(m_1+m_2)}(x^2)\right.\\
&\qquad \quad\left.-\sum_{m_1+2m_2=k,m_1\neq0}\dfrac{k!}{m_1!m_2!}(2x)^{m_1}xG^{(m_1+m_2)}(x^2)\right].
\end{split}
$$
Obtained through Faà di Bruno's formula.